# HOW TO SHOW CURRENT TIME ON TEXTFIELD

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Expanded(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        TimeOfDay? pickedTime =
                                            await showTimePicker(
                                                context: context,
                                                initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                                                initialEntryMode:
                                                    TimePickerEntryMode.dial);

                                        if (pickedTime != null) {
                                          setState(
                                            () {
                                              addActivityStartTimeController
                                                      .text =
                                                  DateFormat("hh:mm")
                                                      .format(DateTime.now());
                                            },
                                          );
                                        }
                                      },
                                      readOnly: true,
                                      minLines: 1,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      validator: (value) =>
                                          addActivityStartTimeValidator(value!),
                                      controller:
                                          addActivityStartTimeController,
                                      //    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.outfit(
                                          fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon:
                                            Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined),
                                        alignLabelWithHint: true,
                                        filled: true,
                                        hintText: "10:20",
                                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.outfit(
                                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                            color: Colors.black54),
                                        fillColor:
                                            ColorConstants.backgroundColor,
                                        focusedErrorBorder:
                                            const OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(10),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10)),
                                        ),
                                        errorStyle: GoogleFonts.outfit(
                                            fontSize: 14.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                            color: Colors.red),
                                        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10)),
                                        ),
                                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(10),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

 onTap: () async {
                                        TimeOfDay? pickedTime =
                                            await showTimePicker(
                                                context: context,
                                                initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                                                initialEntryMode:
                                                    TimePickerEntryMode.dial);

                                        if (pickedTime != null) {
                                          setState(
                                            () {
                                              addActivityStartTimeController
                                                  .text = pickedTime.toString();
                                            },
                                          );
                                        }
                                      },
```

The current view Show some text with time.
Can someone plz explain me how can i show current date and time on text form field

Answer (score 1):

you are doing well
just need to set the datetime string format for Date too

"dd/MM/yyy"  -> date

"hh:mm"  -> time

```
addActivityStartTimeController.text = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm").format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: solved the problem?